# How can I pass a Numpy array into a lambda function that requires only one argument?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy.stats

I am trying to use the scipy.stats.johnsonsu.expect() function on the first column of a numpy array, but the expected value function includes the value from the numpy array:

```
A = [MxN] array of positive floats
b = 2
ev_Array = ss.johnsonsu.expect(func=lambda x: (x * b) - A[:,0], 
                          args=(dstr_params[0], dstr_params[1]),
                          loc=dstr_params[-2],  
                          scale=dstr_params[-1],          
                          lb=A[:,0] / b,
                          ub=upper_bound / b)
```

I recieve this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 241, in <module>
    main()
  File "myfile.py", line 214, in main
    ev_Array = ss.johnsonsu.expect(func=lambda x: (x * b) - A[:,0],
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 2561, in expect
    vals = integrate.quad(fun, lb, ub, **kwds)[0] / invfac
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 348, in quad
    flip, a, b = b < a, min(a, b), max(a, b)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I can do this with normal iteration over a list, but I would like to know how can I pass in A so that the output is an [Mx1] array with the values from .expect(), while within the lambda function A is held constant while calculating the expected value.

Comment: Full traceback on the error.  You/we need to know exactly what operation is producing this error.

Comment: Looks like it's testing that the `ub` is larger than the `lb`.  But you set `lb` to an array: `lb=A[:,0] / b,`.  Bounds for `quad` have to be scalars, single values.  It can't integrate for  multiple bounds.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I have to use iteration for this?  I'm new to programming so I don't know how or if its possible to make `lb` a scalar while updating it for each new value in the array.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ss.johnsonsu.expect`, but generally `quad` calls require iteration if you are trying different ranges or other parameters.  It can handle only one range for a scalar function.